# Is it possible to show a secure third-party web page within my Universal Windows app?

Tags: windows-10-universal

Imagine that I want to display https://www.gmail.com in my Universal Windows app. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a webview control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view. As written in the article, here's how you would implement it.

In xaml

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Source="https://www.gmail.com"/>
```

If you want to navigate it using code:

```
webView1.Navigate("https://www.gmail.com");
```